# Expanded/Collapsed List section at startup

Tags: swift, list

I am struggling to get all the sections of a List collapsed by default. My goal is to create these sections statically(no nested arrays) and **prevent** them to display expanded by default.

```
List()
{
Section(...){}
Section(...){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It's the DisclosureGroup, in case someone needs it.